# Nativescript image to Base64 then fetch POST

Tags: post, base64, fetch, nativescript

How can I Base64 an image so it would be suitable to send with nativescript fetch module?

Answer (score 4):

Here is a basic demo for your case using test server

```
"use strict";
var imageSourceModule = require("image-source");

function navigatingTo(args) {

    var page = args.object;

    // using icon.png from the template app from res://icon
    var imgSrc = imageSourceModule.fromResource("icon");
    var imageAsBase64 = imgSrc.toBase64String("PNG");

    fetch("https://httpbin.org/post", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/octet-stream" },
        body: imageAsBase64
    }).then(function (r) { return r.json(); }).then(function (result) {
        console.log("Base64String: " + result.data);

        // for (var key in result) {
        //     if (result.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        //         var element = object[result];
        //         console.log(key);
        //         console.log(element);
        //         console.log("------")
        //     }
        // }

    }, function (e) {
        console.log("Error occurred " + e);
    });
}
exports.navigatingTo = navigatingTo;
```

Comment: Exactly what I'm looking for!

Comment: You deserve a big fat... thumbs up!

Comment: @Nick lliev, any idea for converting bitmap to Base64 in nativescript?