# Nativescript get base64 data from native image

Tags: javascript, ios, uiimage, nativescript

I try to use https://github.com/bradmartin/nativescript-drawingpad for saving a signature to my backend. But I am simply not capable to find a solution to get some "useful" data from getDrawing(), which returns a native image Object, for example `UIImage` on iOS.

I would love to "convert" the image data to some base64 (png, or whatever) string and send it to my server.

I tried someting like:

```
var ImageModule = require("ui/image");
var ImageSourceModule = require("image-source");

elements.drawingpad.getDrawing().then(function(a){
    var image = ImageSourceModule.fromNativeSource( a );
    api.post("sign", image.toBase64String());
});
```

I also tried to post simply a like seen in the demo stuff.

I would really love to see a demo of how to get my hands on the "image data" itself.

thanks!

Comment: you could find an example how to convert the image to `base64` and to make post request using fetch module in this thread -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38368879/nativescript-image-to-base64-then-fetch-post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @bradmartin I found the solution:

```
var image = ImageSourceModule.fromNativeSource(a);
var base64 = image.toBase64String('png');
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually after lots of digging with tons of error, I finally figured it out.

First you have to require the nativescript-imagepicker source module and also the nativescript image source.

```
var imagepicker         = require("nativescript-imagepicker");
var ImageSourceModule   = require("tns-core-modules/image-source");
```

a case where you want to update a user profile and also send a base64 string to your backend for processing

```
function changeProfileImage(args) {
    var page = args.object;
    var profile = page.getViewById("profile-avatar");
    var context = imagepicker.create({ mode: "single" });
    context.authorize().then(function() {
        return context.present();
    }).then(function(selection) {
        profile.background = `url(${selection[0]._android})`;
        profile.backgroundRepeat = `no-repeat`;
        profile.backgroundSize = `cover`;

        ImageSourceModule.fromAsset(selection[0]).then(image => {
            var base64 = image.toBase64String('png');
            // console.log(base64);
            uploadMediaFile(base64);
        });
    }).catch(function (e) {
        // process error
        console.log(e);
    });
}
```